# How to start an azure webapp or a function app with pulumi

Tags: azure, pulumi

I'm actually managing my IaC and doing ZipDeploy with Pulumi.

Is there a way to add this az cli command to my index.ts in order to start the webapp just after the zip deploy?

```
az webapp start -g myrg -n myapp
```

Comment: Isn't it auto-started? Anyway, it's not a resource-level command, so I believe you can't do this is pulumi.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if Pulumi was also managing the state of a WebApp or VM